# Trying to compile Skia in Android tree under Cygwin

Tags: android, cygwin, skia

I'm trying to compile Skia in Android tree under Cygwin, but I get these error messages:

```
<pre>
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP </br>
PLATFORM_VERSION=3.1.4.1.5.9.2.6.5
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_SIMULATOR=
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=windows
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
============================================
make: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/mycpu/Android/androidsrc'
target asm: libskia 〈= external/skia/src/opts/memset.arm.S
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mfloat-abi=softfp"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mfpu=vfpv3-d16"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-mthumb-interwork"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-psabi"
cc1: warning: -fpic ignored for target (all code is position independent)
cc1: error: bad value (armv7-a) for -march= switch
cc1: error: bad value (armv7-a) for -mtune= switch
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libskia_intermediates
/src/opts/memset.arm.o] Error 1
```

Is it because GCC doesn't support ARMv7-A?